# Google Cloud load balancer redirect if from a certain region

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have two static pages (English, Danish) which are currently in *Google Cloud Storage Bucket*. This bucket contains `en` and `dk` folders for those static pages. Also, I have a Load Balancer with *Google CDN* feature.

I want to achieve that when a person connects to the website from Denmark, that person would get the Danish static page. Meanwhile, people outside Denmark would receive the English site.

**How can I achieve this goal in the load balancer level?**

P.s. I think it can be done with `forwardingRules` but I couldn’t figure out how the rules should look like.

Comment: Does [this](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-load-balancer-backend-buckets) answer your question?

Comment: @Chris32 not completely. I need a country specific separation but not the continental. I assume your answer would work if Google Cloud had servers in Denmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and I think that your needs could be solved with a LB using the [header-based routing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/traffic-management#header-based_and_parameter-based_routing), using the [Accept-Language](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) vary as the routeRules for the URL query.
This [guide](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-traffic-management#http-header-based-routing) can help you to achieve this configuration, but you need to adapt it to be ruled by the Accept-Language header parameters that could be more useful for your case.